# slf4j default binding to java.util.logging

Tags: java, logging, slf4j

I was using a slf4j-api as an interface in my projects. I was trying to provide this projects as a library, so my customer will have to choose which logging framework they want to use.

I know if no binding jar file is provided in the classpath, then the slf4j will simply use a no-op logger implementation which did nothing.

My question is: is there a way to configure slf4j such that if no binding jar file is provided by customer, slf4j will use java.util.logging as a default logging system. And if customer provides an implementation, say log4j, then it will override the default and change to use log4j as logging system.

Comment: Neither log4j nor java.util.logging are compatible logging implementations for slf4j. But in general you are right there should be a way to provide a default fallback implementation other than the NOP logger. Unfortunately the authors of slf4j did not thought that far...

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have solved it by providing another layer on top of java util logging and slf4j-api. If no slf4j library is found in class path, then default to java util logging.